# Django: For Loop to Exclude First Entry

Tags: django, forms, loops, for-loop, field

If I have a forloop that looks something like this:

```
{% for field in form  %}
  {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I modify this to exclude the first entry in the loop? I have tried a few things, but none have worked yet. For example:

```
{% for field in form  %}
{% if field != 1 %}   #also {% if field.id != 1 %}
  {{ field }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also tried:

```
{% if form.field != 1 %}
{% for field in form  %}
  {{ field }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or is there a way to exclude this in my forms.py or views.py that is relatively straightforward? I am using a formwizard so my view and form for this is already pretty complicated... But I appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forloop.first` !

```
{% for field in form  %}
    {% if not forloop.first %}          {#  <-- exclude the first entry #}
        {{ field }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

for reference, check out all the other variables available within a forloop here... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-for